# On Bayesian credible intervals

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

**Question**

Let $X \mid \mu \sim \mathrm{Poisson} (\mu)$ and $\mu \sim \mathrm{Gamma} (1, 1)$ and suppose that a very large number $x$ is observed. Find, in terms of $x$, an approximate $95\%$ Bayesian credible interval for $\mu$. (Hint: $\mathrm{Gamma} (n, 1)$ is the distribution of the sum of $n$ independent $\mathrm{Exponential} (1)$ random variables).

**My thoughts**

The comments have pointed out some of my errors previously and following their suggestions, I have re-worked this.

I have found that $\mu \mid X \sim \mathrm{Gamma} (X + 1, \frac 1 2)$ using shape and scale parameters and since $x$ is large, the Central Limit Theorem can be applied, but I am unsure if the following is correct - does this mean $\frac 1 2 \mu \mid x \sim \mathcal{N} (x + 1, x + 1)$ approximately and since approximately $95\%$ of all normal data falls within $2$ standard deviations of the mean, then an approximate $95\%$ credible interval for $\mu$ is $[2(x + 1 - 2\sqrt{x + 1}), 2(x + 1 + 2\sqrt{x + 1})]$?

---

P.S. We have just covered Bayesian statistics and this is my first ever encounter of a problem asking for a credible interval, so any intuitive explanations will be greatly provided!

Comment: Has the class covered the Central Limit Theorem? What happens to the distribution of a sum of $n$ independent $\mathrm{Exponential} (1)$ random variables, as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @r.e.s. Yes, we have! I know that as $n \to \infty$, most distributions, including the exponential, would tend to normal! However, how might the CLT be relevant here? It is a very large number $x$ that is observed, not a very large number of $x$'s that are observed right? Or would you perhaps be so kind as to elaborate more, maybe in an answer? :)

Comment: You've confused the $n$ in the hint with the $n$ you used in your answer to (a). Your $n$ should be just $1$, as there is only one $X$. The hint is about $x$ (a single realization of $X$) being a large number, etc.

Comment: @EthanMark Yes.  You are asked in (a) to compute the posterior $\mu \mid X$, and **not** $$\mu \mid X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n.$$

Comment: @EthanMark It's too general.  You can recover the answer by setting $n = 1$, hence the posterior is Gamma with shape $\alpha + X$ and scale $\beta/(\beta + 1)$.

Comment: @heropup I see. Actually for $(a)$, I learnt that $f(\mu \mid \underline{X}) \propto f(\mu) f(\underline{X} \mid \mu)$, so in my working I had $\prod^n_{i = 1} \frac {e^{-\mu} \mu^{X_i}} {X_i!}$, but I guess you mean to say I should have just taken $\frac {e^{-\mu} \mu^{X}} {X!}$ instead, because the question is only asking for $f(\mu \mid X) \propto f(\mu) f(X \mid \mu)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and since the shape parameter grows with $x$, which is "very large", apply what you know about the CLT, the shape parameter being the number of summed iid Exponentials.

Comment: The likelihood function contains an $e^{-\mu}$ and the prior has another. So I think you should look again at the parameters of the resulting posterior Gamma distribution.

Comment: @r.e.s. Oh... yes. A careless mistake there. I have edited my post again! Would everything be correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write $\widetilde{\mu}$ to denote the random variable and $\mu$ to denote particular values. We're given the following probability density functions:
$$\begin{align}
f_{X\mid \widetilde{\mu}}(x\mid \mu)&=e^{-\mu}{\mu^x\over x!}{\bf 1}_{x\in\{0,1,2,...\}}\\[2ex]
f_{\widetilde{\mu}}(\mu)&=e^{-\mu}{\bf 1}_{\mu>0}
\end{align}$$
Therefore the posterior density function for $\widetilde{\mu}$ given $X=x\in\{0,1,2,,...\}$ is as follows, where we can write "$\propto$" ("proportional to") and leave out everything that doesn't depend on the distribution variable $\mu$:
$$\begin{align}
f_{\widetilde{\mu}\mid X}(\mu\mid x)&\propto f_{X\mid \widetilde{\mu}}(x\mid \mu)\,f_{\widetilde{\mu}}(\mu)\\[2ex]
&\propto \mu^{(x+1)-1}e^{-2\mu}{\bf 1}_{\mu>0}\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$
i.e., $(\widetilde{\mu}\mid X=x)\sim\text{Gamma(shape=$x+1$, rate=$2$)}.$

But to use the hint, we need to relate this to a Gamma distribution whose rate parameter is $1$, so we recall that for any random variable $Y$, the relation between the densities of $Y$ and $cY$ ($c$ a positive constant) is just $f_{cY}(t)\propto f_Y(t/c)$; so we have
$$\begin{align}
f_{2\widetilde{\mu}\mid X}(t\mid x)&\propto t^{(x+1)-1}e^{-t}{\bf 1}_{t>0}\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$
That is, $(2\widetilde{\mu}\mid X=x)\sim\text{Gamma(shape=$x+1$, rate=$1$)}$. Now, according to the hint, this is the distribution of a sum of $x+1$ iid $\text{Exp($1$)}$ random variables, and we're given that $x$ is "very large"; consequently, we assume the Central Limit Theorem applies to give an approximation:
$$
{(2\widetilde{\mu}\mid X=x)-E(2\widetilde{\mu}\mid X=x)\over \sqrt{V(2\widetilde{\mu}\mid X=x)}}\approx\mathcal{N}(0,1)\\[4ex]
{(2\widetilde{\mu}\mid X=x)-(x+1)\over \sqrt{x+1}}\approx\mathcal{N}(0,1)\\[4ex]
P\left(-z_{1-p/2}< {2\widetilde{\mu}-(x+1)\over \sqrt{x+1}}<z_{1-p/2}\ \middle|\ X=x\right)\approx 1-p\\[4ex]
$$
where $z_q$ denotes the value such that $P(\mathcal{N}(0,1)<z_q)=q$.

An approximate $100(1-p)$% [credible interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval#Choosing_a_credible_interval) for $\widetilde{\mu}$, given $X=x$, is therefore an interval with endpoints
$${1\over 2}(x+1) \pm {1\over 2}z_{1-p/2}\sqrt{x+1} $$
e.g., with $1-p=95$%:$${1\over 2}(x+1) \pm 0.98\sqrt{x+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do correct me if I am wrong, but I am not sure if you have made a minor mistake in your post? I think, for a rate parameter, $\lambda$, if we have $X \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha, \lambda)$, then $\dfrac 1 \lambda X \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha, 1)$ and not $\lambda X \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha, 1)$ as you have written? It is what is written on the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) too (under the Properties section). As I understand it, it is the scale parameter that can be “factorised” out and not the rate, or am I confused?

Comment: @EthanMark The Gamma posterior density of $\widetilde{\mu}$ contains $\exp(-2\mu)$ which can be written as $\exp(-\text{rate}\cdot\mu)$ or $\exp(-\mu/\text{scale})$, as described in the Wikipedia article. (The rate and scale are just reciprocals of each other, the rate being the constant that *multiplies* the variable in the density function, while the scale divides it.) Here the rate is $2$ and the scale is $1/2$ -- but these names are not the important thing, which is that it's $2\widetilde{\mu}$ (not $\widetilde{\mu}/2$) whose density therefore contains the desired $\exp(-\mu).$

Comment: @EthanMark PS ... The properties section at that link says $c\cdot\text{Gamma(shape, rate) $\sim$ Gamma(shape, rate/$c$)}$, agreeing with $\text{rate}\cdot\text{Gamma(shape, rate) $\sim$ Gamma(shape, 1)}$. Maybe what's confusing you about "scale *factors*" is that the constant *multiplier* $c$ in $cY$ is a *divisor* of the variable in the density function of $cY$: $f_{cY}(t)\propto f_Y(t/c).$

Comment: Yes... Indeed I was confused! So I was remembering it wrong all this time... As you say, it is the rate that multiplies the random variable, not the scale. Thank you. That was very important for me :)